# Remove parent div by class name - jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a remove link that will remove the current comment on my page. It uses ajax to change the database and upon success, I want to remove the div the comment resides in. Each comment on the page looks like this:

```
<div class="aComment">
    <span class="commentTitle">Posted by xxx at xxx - <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deleteComment" data-commentid="anID"><img src="resources/images/delete_comment.png" title="Remove this comment" /></a></span>
    <span class="commentText">comment text here</span>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to remove the div once it has returned success. I've tried

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

and no luck. `$(this)` refers to the anchor tag so `parent()` of the anchor should be the `<div class="aComment">` right?

Comment: You need an additional `.parent()` since the parent of the anchor tag is the `span`, not the `div`.

Comment: yep, you are right too, I was off by one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within your Ajax callback `this` does not refer to the anchor element, but even if it did, the `.parent()` method returns the *immediate* parent, i.e., the span element, not the div.

Assuming you have a reference to the anchor, you can say:

```
 $theAnchor.parent().parent().remove();  // get a's parent's parent
```

...but of course that is kind of brittle because if you later change the html structure you have to change the code to. So it is better to use `.closest()` to search up the tree to the nearest ancestor element that matches:

```
$theAnchor.closest("div").remove();
```

You don't show your click handler, but it'll need to be something like this:

```
$(".aComment a").click(function() {
   // keep a reference to the clicked a element for use
   // in the ajax callback
   var $theAnchor = $(this);

   $.ajax(/* your ajax parameters here */, function() {
      $theAnchor.closest("div").remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: so $(".deleteComment").live("click",function() { $(this) }); doesn't refer to the `deleteComment` ?

Comment: In that case yes, `this` refers to the element, but you said you wanted to remove the element once the ajax returned success and I assumed you'd do that from within the ajax callback function at which point `this` does not refer to any particular element (unless you are using `.load()`, which would be weird).

Comment: ahhh ok I understand now and I got it to work. This is what I did..basically what you showed above http://pastie.org/3499974 thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest(".aComment").remove();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/UXWdT/).

The parent of the `a` tag is the `span`. The `div` you are trying to remove is the parent of that `span`.

The reason for using this is simply because it's more convenient than using `parent()` twice.

Comment: Ah you are correct, however it still isn't removing the div. I think it may be due to the fact I am inside a prettyPhoto window: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/ . I will use closest and try and get this to work

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off tackling this by setting an ID for the comment in your code.

For example:

```
<div class="aComment" data-comment-id="5">
```

Then using this ID with your AJAX request and response.

A little more work, but it's more robust (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove it on a click:

```
$(".aComment a").on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest(".aComment").remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaQuu/