# Removing the whole div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Before you mark this as a duplicate, this is how my question is different.**

> Due to the lack of content actually on google, all that I can find is
>   removing the parent ID, I don't think that applies as the parent ID
>   would only remove panel-body, then leave panel-heading and the panel
>   div there.

I wanted to ask a quick question that I couldn't find any help with online. I have a bootstrap panel, which has two div's insdie of it, one for the panel-header and one for the panel-body. Inside the panel-body div I have a btn btn-success button that I want to remove the whole panel on click.

```
<div id="draggable" class="habbo-notification panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Panel Header
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <font color="#B00049">
                    <h1 style="font-size:144px;margin-top:0;margin-left:14px;"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i><h1>
                </font>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>
            Some content here
        </p>
        <br>
        <div class="btn btn-success" onclick="" style="width:100%">Close this</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In javascript or jquery (don't mind which one), how could I remove the entire div onclick of the button, without knowing the ID or class, or having any access to the panel div at all. I declare the panel-body's content somewhere other than the place where I declare the panel and it's two divs panel-body and panel-header.

I want to remove the whole panel div that the button is assigned to, on click?

```
<div class="btn btn-success" onclick="" style="width:100%">Close this</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: I realize this, I have googled it but nothing shows it in this way, my question is different. I'll explain why.

Comment: Remove in "Remove it completely from the DOM" or "hide it"?

Comment: Either is fine, although I would prefer to totally remove it.

Comment: What JavaScript/jQuery have you tried?

Comment: Like I said, I don't know any jquery to try, the jquery I have ran across only removes the parent div, please read in my question at the start.

Comment: Honestly, search for the title of your question. The second result was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3387427/215552).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It says in the question *how could I remove the entire div onclick of the button, without knowing the ID or class*, so I guess your recommendation will not fit here

Comment: @empiric But he does know the ID, or can find it trivially.

Comment: Took me less than a minute to find on Google, how to do this with jQuery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525248/remove-parent-div-by-class-name-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get why you can't use the class(es) of the panel div like .panel, for example:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
     $(".panel").css("display","none");
});
```

But I think this would technically also work:

```
 $(".btn").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().parent().css("display","none");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery method is this one-liner.

```
$('.btn-success').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('div.panel').remove();
});
```

The [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function looks for the nearest parent matching the supplied selector. In this case, it checks each parent of `this` until it sees `div.panel`.

You could drop this in your `onclick=""`, though on*event* attributes are deprecated in HTML. Standards expect events to be set within the Javascript.